# initializing array pointer to a struct

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I get the Error run-time check failure #3, and i have to initialize P and i know why but not how to do it.

Points is supposed to be a variable 2D array like float* points[3] for testing purposes its constant for now.

```
CVAPI(CvPOSITObject*)  lvCreatePOSITObject( float points[5][3], int point_count )
{
    CvPoint3D32f* P; //array of structs with int x,y,z 
    for(int i = 0; i< point_count; i++)
    {
        P[i].x = points[i][0];
        P[i].y = points[i][1];
        P[i].z = points[i][2];
    }
    return cvCreatePOSITObject(P,point_count);
}
```

Comment: What does `cvCreatePOSITObject()` do? This is essential to know, for deciding which solution to take, as there are multiple.

Comment: a value of type void* cannot be used to initialize an entity of type CvPoint3D32f, also is it possible to use malloc(point_count, sizeof(CVPoint3D32f))?
it creates a opencv structure from points

Comment: `malloc(point_count, sizeof(CVPoint3D32f))` should have read `calloc(point_count, sizeof(CVPoint3D32f))`?

Comment: same error as with malloc

Comment: Which compiler, which platform?

Comment: `malloc(point_count, sizeof(CVPoint3D32f))` shouldn't even compile.

Comment: vista visual studio 2010 c/c++

Comment: Then go to the Project's properties and select "*Configuration Properties -> C/C++ -> Advanced*" and set "*Compile As*" to "*Compile as C Code*", otherwise you are using the C++ compiler, which indeed does not accept assigning a `void*` to any other pointer typed variable without casting it.

Comment: that did not change anything

Answer (score 1):

I don't know much about OpenCV, but I think you should **allocate** some memory to store the data.

```
#include <stdlib.h> // add this to the head of the file to use malloc

CVAPI(CvPOSITObject*)  lvCreatePOSITObject( float points[5][3], int point_count )
{
    CvPoint3D32f* P; //array of structs with int x,y,z
    P = malloc(sizeof(CvPoint3D32f) * point_count); // allocate some memory
    for(int i = 0; i< point_count; i++)
    {
        P[i].x = points[i][0];
        P[i].y = points[i][1];
        P[i].z = points[i][2];
    }
    return cvCreatePOSITObject(P,point_count);
}
```

This code may be bad because this may not free the allocated buffer.

Comment: malloc says: a value of type void* cannot be used to initialize an entity of type CvPoint3D32f freeing the memory happens in another function

Comment: @Eumel: Mind the `*`  in `CvPoint3D32f* P;`!

Comment: oh yes there should be a * there